# How to cancel windows phone task that uses await

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, task

I have this code that start a Task thread that calls a method to read data in a StreamSocket whenever it becomes available. Iy also takes a a cancellation token.

```
await Task.Factory.StartNew(ProcessMessage, CancelToken);
```

But after i call this method.

```
CancelToken.Cancel();
```

My app stills run the ProcessMessage method when i get new data in the StreamSocket. Which shouldn't be happening.  It think its because i use await on it.

How can I get this task to stop when the Token is cancelled?

Comment: You should [prefer `Task.Run` over `Task.Factory.StartNew` in `async` code](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html), as I explain on my blog.

Answer (score 0):

When you issue `CancellationToken.Cancel()`, the `IsCancellationRequested` property on every copy of the cancellation token is set to true. The objects that receive the notification can respond in whatever manner is appropriate. The typical pattern is to call `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` within your loop somewhere.

So in your `ProcessMessage` routine, you need something like

```
while (processing) 
{
    // carry on your processing...

    // Poll on this property if you have to do other cleanup before throwing. 
    if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        // Clean up here, then...
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    }
}
```

You can find guidelines on implementing cancellation with await [in the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364.aspx).

Comment: Thank for the answer. But this doesnt work. It still processes the message even after i cancel the token. Here is my ProcessMessage class:  http://pastebin.com/uAXjy8sW

Comment: You are ignoring the `OperationCancelledException` with your `catch`. Either remove it or `throw` again. You might also need to `ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` from within `serverRequest(msg)` if that could be a lengthy operation.